# Magento 2 Blank Admin New Install

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I use Windows 10. I am trying to install Magento 2 using XAMPP. My admin screen is blank and I get these errors:

Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559567140/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559567140/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559567140/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559567140/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559567140/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1559567140/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
require.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
mixins.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
requirejs-config.js:536 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at requirejs-config.js:536
opensans-400.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opensans-400.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image: Blank admin]

Comment: What version of Magento2? Versions newer than 2.2.5 don't work on Windows - you need to install a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: I have 2.3.1. I will uninstall and install an older edition.

Comment: You'd be better off slapping on something like Oracle VirtualBox and running a Debian/Ubuntu VM; just don't use shared folders, it makes deploying content (e.g. setup:di:compile) slow as all hell.

Comment: The error is almost certainly a red herring. If you try to open one of the css files directly, you'll probably find you get a 404 not found. You're problem is likely to be you haven't created your css files properly. If you google around you'll find this is a common problem (I've had it!).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: If you use windows machine Please change the path on this location "vendor/magento/framework/view/element/template/file/validator.php"

From 
 $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
To
 $realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

Step 2: Check Your root .htaccess
Remove IfVersion

Step 3: Remove IfVersion from pub/.htaccess and pub/Static/.htaccess

Hope working as per acceptation. If you face any problem Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Hope no need of any code change. You already done installation successfully right.?
Please check below things are proper in your side.

- check rewrite a2enmod is enabled or not.
- Try to re run your deployment command again and give necessary permissions. for your local you can have full permissions for var/*,generate/*,app/etc/*,pub/static* (remember to remove app/etc full permission when you going live)
- Note for magento2.3 you need php7.2 support

Hope this will help you out

Answer (score 0):

1. ...\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
2. In function isPathInDirectories added a line
    $realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $realPath);

   `$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // This is the code you extra added.`

Comment: In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1 first check your deploy model and set developer

php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

2 open file

/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php
in magento install dir , find

$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
replace with :

$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

open file
app/etc/di.xml
in magento install dir, find

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace with

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Have a try.